# When using pthreads in C++ on Ubuntu. Where does the main thread scope start and end?

Tags: c++, class, ubuntu, pthreads

So I'm not immediately posting code here because I'm a student and know that my code is currently pretty ugly and in this case quite large.

Question 1:
That said I'm trying to trouble shoot my situation more so than get someone else's solution to my problem. That said, for starters I'm just looking for a simple answer to the question of the lifetime of the main thread scope when the pthread_create function is called in a member function of a class. Does that member function act as the main thread, does the main thread travel into other member functions called within that member function? Or does the main thread even travel out of that function, say if that function is being called in a loop from another function, would the main thread exist in that outer function, reminder that the pthread_create function was called in a function in a loop in an outer function?

Question 2:
Since I needed to use a wrapper for the callee function to work with a class member would I use pthread_exit in my wrapper function or in my wrapped function? And any insight into the structure of things when being done this way that may differ from doing things without classes would be greatly appreciated.

Question 3:
Set up, I'm attempting to store my thread ID's as an array of unsigned long ints in my class but whenever I try to use one of these in a pthread_join function it breaks. Does it need to be an array of pthread_t'? What is the difference between a pthread_t and an unsigned long?

Just a reminder I am a student not a professional, please try to take that into account in answers, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm more than willing to post code if it comes to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Pthread creation is a completely asynchronous operation. Your main thread makes the call to create, which starts the new thread based on the parameters given, and returns immediately to execute the next line of code. That main thread continues as it otherwise would with no regard to the newly created thread. Meanwhile, the new thread executes in parallel. You seem a little confused about scoping. To put it simply, that new thread will continue to exist until it exits, regardless of what scope (within a loop for example) it was created within. Similarly, the main thread scope makes no difference. It just starts the new thread and continues as if nothing had happened. In general, they are completely unaware of each others existence, they just share your processes memory space.

3 - The type is pthread_t, so store it as such. Always avoid storing one type as something else unless you have good reason to do so. This may answer your question about the difference (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/concep17.htm)

Comment: But my 'main' as in my 'int main(){...}' is not where the call to 'pthread_create(...)' is happening. It is happening in a member function of a class. So is the main thread still the thread that is created in 'main' or is the member function where the pthread_create() is called considered to be the 'main' thread of that split thread. P.S That link totally answered my third question, thanks.

Comment: @Gaetano There is only one 'main' thread. That thread will execute 'int main' as well as the member function. threads are unrelated to the functions that they are executing, ie when a thread is executing 'int main', and encounters a call to memberFunction, the same thread jumps to memberFunction and starts executing there. When is it done executing memberFunction, it jumps back to 'int main' and continues execution

Comment: Thanks. That is how I thought it worked but the errors I was getting was leading me to wonder other wise. I'm still trying to figure out how to store my thread ID somewhere so that I can join in a different function then the one where it is created. This is my first time working with threads and was given very little info to get going on so I appreciate the input.